# understanding rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple questions but since they all are somewhat associated I thought about asking it in the same thread.

So basically I am having tough time understanding React rendering strategy so I broke this into simpler terms for which I am seeking help to understand

**Question 1:**

Does React re-render only when state changes?

**Question 2:**

Suppose I have a parent stateful component ( class something extends component), Also in the file, we import multiple things like

```
import Post from '../../components/Post/Post';
import FullPost from '../../components/FullPost/FullPost';
import NewPost from '../../components/NewPost/NewPost';
```

and hence making it something like this in return

```
render () {
      console.log(this.state.error)
    let newPosts = <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}> Sorry some error </p>
      if (!this.state.error) {
        newPosts = this.state.posts.map(el => {
          return <Post key={el.id}
           title={el.title}
           author={el.author}
           clicked={() =>this.postClicked(el.id)}/>
        })
    }

return (
            <div className="Blog">
              <header>
                <nav>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="/new-post">New Post</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </header>
                <section className="Posts">
                  {newPosts}
                </section>
                <section>
                    <FullPost id={this.state.selectedPostId}/>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <NewPost />
                </section>
            </div>
```

So when our state changes, will it render everything here associated the state? Like everything inside `FullPost` or `newPosts`?

**Question 3:**

`FullPost` (or `newPosts`) happens to be the children of the above post, now if, inside our full post our state changes, will it also render components in our parent class?

Also, if you can share anything interesting about React state change/render would be very helpful.

Comment: You have too many questions here. Please consider splitting them up into separate questions.

Comment: **(1)** Yes, and on prop changes too. **(2)** Don't confuse "re-render" with "re-mounting" - the former means that the `render()` method is invoked after the initial render whereas the latter means a component is replaced with a new one in the DOM. React will only re-mount and/or update the DOM when necessary. Please read: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html. **(3)** No. Children don't invoke re-renders of their parents. Only the vice-versa happens.

Comment: Read https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/ and you would love it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. React rerenders when,
   a) SetState is called, or state's value changes
   b) props changes
   c) forceUpdate() is called(this is going to be deprecated)
2. everything inside FullPost or newPosts ?
   No, when the state changes or rerender is initiated, only the render function gets called again, and from react 16.3 onwards, getDerivedStateFromProps() also gets called.
   Another function which gets called before a render on state/props update is shouldComponentUpdate()
3. Changes in state/props of child components will only rerender child component. But if a parent component is rerendered, its child component is also rerendered.